# Error in spring-boot appplication : This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

I have created a simple spring boot application in Eclipse which has User class and I have written web services to perform various operations on User such as get-users, create-user, delete-user.

When I am testing the application from the browser, I am getting the below error:
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

The path that I used: http://localhost:8080/user/get-user/Mike
I have annotated User resource class @RestController and Application class @SpringBootApplication.

Code snippet :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/user/get-user/{name}" )
public User getUserByName(@PathVariable String name) {
    
    System.out.println("Request for name: "+name);
    return service.getUser(name); // this return the first user found with given name
}
```

Here is my project structure:
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ryDu.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just had a look at your project structure. In your case, you need to ensure that your main class is in a root package above other classes.

Whenever a Spring Boot Application is started or run (example : `Application.java` or a class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`), it scans the classes below your main class package.

An example would be :

```
com
   +- test
         +- Application.java 
         |
         +- controller
         |   +- UserRestController.java
         +- domains
             +- User.java
```

Try this and check.
Also, please ensure that you have added all the necessary annotations required on all the required classes for a Spring boot application for work correctly.

Comment: ,thanks for your feedback. I checked again and could see that all annotations are correct. Also the structure of project is also same as you suggested, isn't it ? Application.java is my SpringBootApplication annotated class and it is first in the structure.

Comment: @borkarda , please check again. Your Application.java is not at above other packages in  src/main/java. It is actually parallel to controller class and other classes. It should work once you correctly restructure it.

Comment: thanks again. It worked now. I also tried, below code and this is also one of the way of doing it.  I made changes to Application class as @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.md5.rest.webservices.*")

Answer (score 1):

In my case (I ended up here, looking for a solution, Stackoverflow is great!), I had forgotten to add the thymeleaf dependency.